# How to share a ViewModel between different pages in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am trying to share a ViewModel between pages.

Say I have pageA.html and pageB.html and a separate data.js file. pageA has fields bound (using Knockout) and after clicking a button it moves to pageB which also has some fields bound to the same ViewModel. I can't get this to work - what am I missing?

Of course I can keep all pages (data-role="page") inside a single .html file and it would work fine but is that the only way?

EDIT - pageB.html is a copy of pageA - I am trying to show the problem NOT having another login functionality in many pages!!!

This is the code:

**pageA.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang="en">
    <title>PageA</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/data.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="login">

        <div id="loginDetails">

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="username">
                    Username:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="username" data-bind="value: userid" />
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="pswd">
                    Password:</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="pswd" data-bind="value: pswd" />
            </div>

        </div>

        <a id="btnLogin" data-role="button" data-bind="click: login">Login</a>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        ko.applyBindings(S5.myViewModel);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**pageB.html** (largely the same as above but its javascript block doesn't seem to get called...)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head lang="en">
    <title>pageB</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script src="JS/data.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="abcd">

        <div id="loginDetails">

            <input type="text" name="name" data-bind="value: userid" />

            <input type="text" name="name" data-bind="value: pswd" />

        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        debugger;   <-- THIS NEVER GETS CALLED!!

        ko.applyBindings(S5.myViewModel);

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**data.js**

```
var S5;

(function (S5) {

    S5.myViewModel = {
        userid: ko.observable('marcel'),
        pswd: ko.observable('xxx'),
        login: function () {

            // ** DO LOGIN CHECK then move to pageB

            $.mobile.changePage("pageB.html", { transition: "slideup" });
        },
    };

})(S5 || (S5 = {}));
```

Comment: try moving JS block inside `data-role=page` div.

Comment: YES - that and narrowing the binding of the ViewModel to the specific element did the trick - thanks again Omar :)  !!

Comment: Can you write this as the answer so I can mark it answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile uses Ajax Navigation to load and change views. When using multi-html page template, it loads first page (html file) entirely. However, for other views /pages fetched with Ajax, it loads contents inside `<body>` only, neglecting other tags i.e. `<script>`, `<head>` etc...

To solve your problem, move any extra JS libraries or code inside `<div data-role="page">`.